# Change background color of Jupyter notebooks

Tags: pycharm

I use PyCharm Community Edition with a dark background. When plotting in a Jupyter Notebook, the labels and the units of the axis are black on dark background, hence unreadable. 
Is there a way of changing the background color for the Jupyter Notebooks only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem. According to the below, it's not possible unfortunately.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205435570-Jupyter-notebook-ouput-appearance

Comment: For `matplotlib` and `darcula` PyCharm theme I added the following  line: `ax.tick_params(axis='x', colors='white')` for `x`, and for `y` axis you can do the same.